# How to release memory of mysql connection open when working on c#

Tags: c#, mysql, garbage-collection

```
MySqlConnection con = null;
con = new MySqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = @"Connection_string";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;

try
{
      con.Open();   //Its increasing the memory size up to 4 mb

      ///--------------------------Logic----------------------//


     ///------------------------------------------------------//

   con.close();  //It does not work : memory does not reallocate.
}
catch
{

}
```

Comment: i have tried connection.dispose();  but not releasing memory

Comment: "Ok, can you please explain me what a garbage collector is and how I can release memory in .NET and generally I never bothered to read any documentation on how the whole memory model works". Is that about it? .NET has a garbage collection model. You do not deallocate memory. The runtime collects unused memory - WHEN IT NEEDS IT.

Comment: connection.open();   why it increase lot of memory

Comment: connection.open();   why it increase lot of memory   But connection.close(); why not decrease memory?

Comment: Define "log of memory"? Come one, we can not teach you the gbasics of .NET.

Comment: GC.Collect();
   GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

   Dispose(true);

  GC.SuppressFinalize(this);                 none of these not                           working

Comment: Be aware that if you are debugging then the GC will not collect any variables that are still in scope, even if they are never referenced again.

Comment: is your application REALLY that sensitive that this connection is creating an issue? Under normal circumstances, automatic memory management by the .Net Framework is more than sufficient; if memory is a problem for your app, perhaps using a managed language is the wrong approach to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try to use try - final block and always close connections / commands on final block or use using statement
2. Use a connection pool, where then the connections will be re-used and then amount of memory won't go higher than certain amount.

What you observe here (not clearing up memory when you close the connection), is probably because even if you close the connection GC won't be collecting it effective immediately, and it won't trigger until your application maxed out the stack

Comment: plz any small example

Comment: using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection()){ do stuff here... }